# how to know which type of user I am?

Tags: 14.04, networking

while reading about linux ,I got :: By default, Linux distinguishes between several account types in order to isolate `processes` and `workloads`. Linux has four types of accounts:

- Root
- System
- Normal
- Network

now when I tried $last on my shell , I got :

```
anupam@JAZZ:~$ last
anupam   pts/0        :0               Fri Oct 10 09:38   still logged in   
anupam   tty1                          Fri Oct 10 09:35   still logged in   
anupam   :0           :0               Fri Oct 10 09:27   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Fri Oct 10 09:26 - 09:39  (00:12)    
anupam   pts/24       :0               Thu Oct  9 23:57 - 23:58  (00:00)    
anupam   pts/23       :0               Thu Oct  9 23:26 - 23:58  (00:31)    
anupam   pts/9        :0               Thu Oct  9 23:07 - 23:58  (00:50)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Thu Oct  9 23:05 - down   (01:23)    
anupam   :0           :0               Thu Oct  9 22:50 - down   (01:37)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Thu Oct  9 22:50 - 00:28  (01:38)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Thu Oct  9 21:44 - down   (01:05)    
anupam   :0           :0               Thu Oct  9 18:57 - down   (03:52)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Thu Oct  9 18:56 - 22:49  (03:52)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Thu Oct  9 11:07 - crash  (07:49)    
anupam   :0           :0               Thu Oct  9 10:58 - crash  (07:58)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Thu Oct  9 10:58 - 22:49  (11:51)    
anupam   pts/10       :0               Thu Oct  9 01:30 - 02:21  (00:51)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Wed Oct  8 22:56 - 02:34  (03:38)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Wed Oct  8 18:50 - 21:19  (02:29)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Wed Oct  8 18:09 - 18:50  (00:40)    
anupam   :0           :0               Wed Oct  8 17:50 - down   (08:44)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Wed Oct  8 17:50 - 02:34  (08:44)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Wed Oct  8 12:33 - 12:33  (00:00)    
anupam   :0           :0               Wed Oct  8 10:35 - down   (07:14)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Wed Oct  8 10:34 - 17:49  (07:14)    
anupam   :0           :0               Tue Oct  7 20:13 - down   (13:41)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Tue Oct  7 20:13 - 09:55  (13:41)    
anupam   tty1                          Tue Oct  7 20:09 - down   (00:02)    
anupam   pts/23       :0               Tue Oct  7 20:00 - down   (00:11)    
anupam   pts/16       :0               Tue Oct  7 19:54 - down   (00:17)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Tue Oct  7 16:45 - down   (03:26)    
anupam   :0           :0               Tue Oct  7 16:32 - down   (03:39)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Tue Oct  7 16:32 - 20:11  (03:39)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Tue Oct  7 10:48 - 16:31  (05:42)    
anupam   :0           :0               Tue Oct  7 10:09 - down   (06:21)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Tue Oct  7 10:08 - 16:31  (06:22)    
anupam   :0           :0               Mon Oct  6 23:35 - down   (02:15)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Mon Oct  6 23:35 - 01:50  (02:15)    
anupam   pts/3        :0               Mon Oct  6 22:53 - down   (00:11)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Mon Oct  6 22:40 - 23:04  (00:24)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Mon Oct  6 11:26 - 19:07  (07:40)    
anupam   tty1                          Mon Oct  6 10:48 - down   (12:16)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Mon Oct  6 10:47 - 11:26  (00:39)    
anupam   :0           :0               Mon Oct  6 10:09 - down   (12:55)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Mon Oct  6 10:08 - 23:05  (12:56)    
anupam   :0           :0               Sun Oct  5 13:21 - down   (19:59)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Sun Oct  5 13:21 - 09:21  (19:59)    
anupam   :0           :0               Sun Oct  5 08:37 - down   (04:43)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Sun Oct  5 08:36 - 13:20  (04:43)    
anupam   tty1                          Sat Oct  4 18:29 - down   (07:23)    
anupam   :0           :0               Sat Oct  4 16:22 - down   (09:30)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Sat Oct  4 16:21 - 01:52  (09:30)    
anupam   pts/9        :0               Sat Oct  4 12:37 - down   (03:43)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Sat Oct  4 10:49 - down   (05:31)    
anupam   :0           :0               Sat Oct  4 09:00 - down   (07:19)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Sat Oct  4 09:00 - 16:20  (07:20)    
anupam   :0           :0               Fri Oct  3 20:49 - down   (12:09)    
anupam   tty1                          Fri Oct  3 20:48 - down   (12:10)    
anupam   :0           :0               Fri Oct  3 12:39 - 20:49  (08:09)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Fri Oct  3 12:39 - 08:59  (20:19)    
anupam   pts/13       :0               Fri Oct  3 00:50 - down   (01:38)    
anupam   pts/7        :0               Thu Oct  2 23:33 - down   (02:54)    
anupam   tty1                          Thu Oct  2 23:27 - down   (03:01)    
anupam   tty2                          Thu Oct  2 22:27 - 23:06  (00:38)    
anupam   pts/7        :0               Thu Oct  2 19:42 - 23:04  (03:21)    
anupam   pts/7        :0               Thu Oct  2 19:34 - 19:42  (00:08)    
anupam   pts/7        :0               Thu Oct  2 19:24 - 19:24  (00:00)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Thu Oct  2 19:24 - down   (07:03)    
anupam   tty1                          Thu Oct  2 18:24 - 23:06  (04:42)    
anupam   :0           :0               Thu Oct  2 15:48 - down   (10:39)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Thu Oct  2 15:48 - 02:28  (10:40)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Thu Oct  2 11:18 - 15:45  (04:26)    
anupam   :0           :0               Thu Oct  2 10:11 - down   (05:34)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Thu Oct  2 09:33 - 15:45  (06:12)    
anupam   pts/0        :0               Wed Oct  1 19:08 - 01:40  (06:31)    
anupam   :0           :0               Wed Oct  1 18:28 - down   (07:14)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-36-generi Wed Oct  1 18:28 - 01:43  (07:14)    

wtmp begins Wed Oct  1 15:18:10 2014
```

here , I am just getting the `System Account type` corresponds to `system boot` in second attribute ,, Can I get some other commands where I can get interact with other Account Types i.e. `Network,Normal`(I think I am running it ,isn't it?),`Root`(by using sudo ,isn't it?),, 
What does the last line `wtmp begins Wed Oct  1 15:18:10 2014` means?

Comment: Only one question per one post Jazzz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What does the last line wtmp begins Wed Oct 1 15:18:10 2014 means?*

That means your system started writing log records of login activity from  Wed Oct 1 15:18:10 2014.

wtmp is a process of writing login activity to a log file. so if you want to see login activity then you can be able to see from the moment wtmp started running.

for more information you can see it manpage & Google is your friend.

hope it helps.